# loop trough two arrays of objects with include() and return nearest/exact match

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I know, that there are many similar questions like this, but I cannot find an answer to my case.

So I am struggling with the following:

I have two array of objects which I am looping trough each other and am trying to fish out a street name. The catch is, to get only the name, which is nearest. I'll explain it below:

```
const obj1 = [
{ name: "I am the one and only", address: "street name 123, 456" },
{ name: "I am here only to fill up the place", address: "to not be a 1 element long array of objects"}
]

const obj2 = [
{ name: "testA", street: "street name 123" },
{ name: "testB", street: "street name 1" },
{ name: "testC", street: "street name" }
]

for ( let i of obj1 ) {
  for ( let j of obj2 ) {
    if(i.address.includes(j.street)) {
      console.log(i, j)
    }
  }
}
```

expected output:

```
{
  address: "street name 123, 456",
  name: "I am the one and only"
}, {
  name: "testA",
  street: "street name 123"
}
```

what I got:

```
{
  address: "street name 123, 456",
  name: "I am the one and only"
}, {
  name: "testA",
  street: "street name 123"
}
{
  address: "street name 123, 456",
  name: "I am the one and only"
}, {
  name: "testB",
  street: "street name 1"
}
{
  address: "street name 123, 456",
  name: "I am the one and only"
}, {
  name: "testC",
  street: "street name"
}
```

Link to my playground: [CodeSandboxLink](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-cannon-zzvu2k?file=/src/index.js)

My question is, how to achieve my expected result? Tried it with regex, but it cannot find any formula, that could help in my case.

Comment: But "street name 1" and "street name" actually are "similar" to "streetname 123, 456". If you want more restrictive comparisons you need information on how streetnames will be formatted. Regex will be your friend, but not without a clear understanding of how to extract the precise values you need. For example, would you accept "123 street name" as an answer? If so, that changes the game...

Comment: what if you have mode same length matching strings? what is better/wanted?

Comment: @MichaelBeeson well, I cannot accept "123 street name". But do you mean, that I should do a reversed string search and after the search is complete, I should un-reverse the answers?

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks for the tip, but the street names length vary, so it ain't a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach.

You could build a score list and choose the one with the largest score.

The score is made of matching strings and their length.

```js
const
    data1 = [{ name: "I am the one and only", address: "street name 123, 456" }, { name: "I am here only to fill up the place", address: "to not be a 1 element long array of objects"}],
    data2 = [{ name: "testA", street: "street name 123" }, { name: "testB", street: "street name 1" }, { name: "testC", street: "street name" }],
    scores = {};

data1.forEach(({ address }, i) => {
    data2.forEach(({ street }, j) => {
        if (address.includes(street)) scores[[i, j].join('|')] = street.length / address.length;
    });
});

console.log(scores);
```